# Can I limit Gmail auto-retrieval on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

Is it possible to stop the iPhone from retrieving old emails from my mail account? I have about 5000 messages in my Gmail inbox and would like to keep them there. Currently, my iPhone fetches about 50 at a time and displays them in my inbox.

Is there a way to setup iPhone mail to fetch only future emails, or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have setup your Gmail using Google Sync (as an Exchange account) then it is doable. If you'd like to do this follow these instructions:

[Set up Google Sync with your iOS device](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740)

There are other benefits to this such as Exchange-like calendar pushing and *proper* push support for mail.

Then, go to the *Settings* app and under *Mail, Contacts, Calendars* select the account you want to limit the retrieval of mail for.

Underneath the sliders that enable the components of the account (e.g. contacts, calendars or mail) you will have the following option

- Mail Days to Sync
- Mail Folders to Push

The first of these is what you want. If set to 2 weeks then only the last 2 weeks of mail is synced with your phone.

I prefer however to have *No Limit* with this option and choose to limit which folders get synced (with the second option). If you keep a tidy inbox and archive mail to folders then this can be a sensible way forward.